# WSO 7.0 Micro Integrator multiple odata services

Tags: wso2, odata, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

As the Odata Service in Micro Integrator 7.x has to use keywords "odata_service" and "Datasource", it is right only one Odata Service can be built in one WSO2 Micro Integrator instance?

Is the only work around (to have muliple Odata Service) is to have mulitple MI instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"odata_service" and "Datasource" are not keywords. I am assuming you are referring to this documentation https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/next/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/data_integration/odata-service/

The above values are shown as example. You can create multiple DataServices with ODataEnabled with different service name and dataservice id in a single Micro Integrator instance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad, when I first tried that, I did experience some problems until I change the services names and dataservice id to exactly the the same with what's in the document. But when I tried again today, everything works fine no matter what those values are. And can create multiple odata services easily. I must went crazy the other day! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries :-) It happens